# Results UNDEFINED in SQL query and php

Tags: php, sql, substring

I am new when it comes to php, SQL and still learning, I am trying to get the last 4 string value of my column where the value is a telephone numbers: (7258787) 
I am trying to display the last 4 string even the search query is full 7 string (8787) base on what i have read SUBSTRING(column_name, -4) will result the last 4 strings from the right.
my codes returns undefined, can you enlighten me with this?

```
    if (isset($_GET['telephone'])) {
    $data = "%".$_GET['telephone']."%";
    $sql = 'SELECT telephone, SUBSTRING(telephone,-4)FROM employee';
```

Using this:

```
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE telephone like ?';
```

will result the correct value of 7258787 but it will result the whole string(telephone numbers) that i type on a search box

Thank you in advance

This is the whole code:

This is not the answer but the whole script, (credits to Israel Barragan)
In my database I have employee as table and the columns are 'ID', 'NAME', 'TELEPHONE', and 'EMAIL'

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once 'Connectiondb.php';
$conn = dbConnect();
$OK = true; // We use this to verify the status of the update.

if (isset($_GET['telephone'])) {
    // Create the query
    $data = "%".$_GET['telephone']."%";
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE telephone like ?';
    // we have to tell the PDO that we are going to send values to the query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // Now we execute the query passing an array toe execute();
    $results = $stmt->execute(array($data));
    // Extract the values from $result
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    //echo $error[2];
}
// If there are no records.
if(empty($rows)) {
    echo json_encode( array('error'=>'There were not records','0'=> 'There            were not records'));
}
else {
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

sorry I am new to stackoverflow,

Comment: Can you post some more code? How you select second query? Did you try to print the result from it before go to the next page?

Comment: What database is this? Try putting a column alias and a space in ` SUBSTRING(telephone,-4)FROM` so that it looks like ` SUBSTRING(telephone,-4) as phoneLastFour FROM`

Comment: Okey sorry let me put the whole code, and thank you

Comment: @Leiagh edit your original post to add the code, please don't put it in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the result in your query, and then get the last 4 digits from that to display.

For instance, you can do this

(not you aren't binding your parameters.  You need to do something like this)

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $data);
```

and then execute it like this:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

In your query instead of using `select *`, name the specific keys and then you can bind the result like this (assuming all you need is the phone number:

```
$stmt->bind_result($telephone);
```

then get the result like so:

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

then you can just get a substring off of `$telephone` like so  (in php it is `substr()`)

```
echo substr($telephone,-4);
```

(oh yeah and don't forget to close your object with

```
$stmt->close();
```

after you are done)

Edit:
Here's your query put together to get the substring

```
$data = "%".$_GET['telephone']."%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT telephone FROM employee WHERE telephone like ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $data);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($telephone);
$stmt->fetch();
echo substr($telephone,-4);
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I am having a problem; :((

Comment: @Leiagh  Not sure what issue you are still having, but I edited my answer to put it all together.  The above code should work for you